# Error with two classes that #include each other

Tags: c++, include

So lets say I have a class called `Foo` and another called `Bar`.  `Bar` contains an instance of `Foo` and I have a function in `Foo` that takes `Bar` as a parameter.  However, when I `#include "Bar.h"` in `Foo` to allow `Foo` to see `Bar` I get this error on the lines that `Bar` is referenced on:

> error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Foo' with no type

I'm guessing this is because both of the classes rely on each other to compile.  Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT: Both of these classes have header files where the other class is referenced inside a `#ifndef` declaration.

Comment: If you have to include each other classes you should overthink your program design. Something is wrong here.

Comment: Consider what the output of the preprocessor will look like. Figure out what it should look like, and that's a huge step in telling which of the headers doesn't need to include the other.

Comment: If a class body is not yet visible then you need to forward declare it. However, you cannot use the object of the class just with a forward declaration. You need to have class body visible to have its object.

Comment: @juergend Overthinking may be the problem, but is rarely the solution... rethinking, perhaps :)

Answer (score 3):

In `Foo.h` instead of including `Bar.h` you need to use the forward declaration `class Bar;`. Note that for this to work you need to take the parameter `Bar` as a reference or a pointer in `Foo` class.

Comment: In `struct bar; struct foo { void frob(bar); };`, `bar` doesn't have to be complete. Only when you need to define a member variable you need to have a complete type (otherwise compiler wouldn't be able to compute the size of `foo`).

Answer (score 0):

Use references or pointers for parameters and forward declarations. E.g.

```
//foo.h
class Bar;// the forward declaration
class Foo {
void myMethod(Bar*);
};

//foo.cpp
#include "bar.h"
void Foo::myMethod(Bar* bar){/* ... */}

//bar.h 
#include "foo.h"
class Bar {
  /*...*/
  Foo foo;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{

};

and

class Bar;
class Foo
{
};
```

**But this might be a result of a wrong design!!**

Comment: A bunch of classes with no circularity could also be the result of a wrong design. Circularity does not stand out as a marker of bad design.

Comment: But isnt it something we try to avoid if we could?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a forward declaration for at least one class:

Foo.h:

```
#include "Bar.h"

class Foo {

};
```

Bar.h:

```
class Bar;

#include "Foo.h"

class Bar {

};
```

Also beware that you cannot easily reference members of Bar in Foo.h (they're not declared).  So any inlined members that need Bar will have to go in Foo.cpp (or .cc if you prefer).  You also cannot have a Bar as a value member of Foo.

So:

```
class Bar {
    Foo f; // OK. Compiler knows layout of Foo.
};

class Foo {
    Bar b; // Nope. Compiler error, details of Bar's memory layout not known.
    Bar *b; // Still OK.
};
```

This is especially tricky for templates.  See the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html) if you have troubles.